# How to keep a ToolTip on a control open when mouse moves away

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

N.B. I cannot use a Popup. It has to be a ToolTip. The reason is as a frustrating for me as it is for anyone, but it has to be a ToolTip.

Is it possible to override the FrameworkElement.ToolTipOpening, FrameworkElement.ToolTipClosing, ToolTip.Opened, or ToolTip.Closed events to keep the ToolTip open such that it stays open and allows me to place interactive controls on the ToolTip?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting

```
ToolTip.IsOpen = true;
ToolTip.StaysOpen = true;
```

From MSDN:

Remarks

---

A value of false for the StaysOpen property is not supported for a ToolTip when it is not open. To create a tooltip that stays open until the mouse button is pressed when it is outside the tooltip, you must set both the StaysOpen property and the IsOpen property to true. If StaysOpen is set to false when the tooltip is not open, a NotSupportedException occurs.

I haven't tried this but, from the MDSN text I'm guessing in the Opened event handler you can set StaysOpen and IsOpen both to true and the ToolTip should remain open until the user clicks somewhere outside the ToolTip.

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't look like StaysOpen does jack. I even checked to make sure StaysOpen wasn't being modified by someone else, but on the tooltip.Opened event, StaysOpen is still true, and the functionality is no different.

Comment: Well, like I said, I hadn't actually tried it, just thought it was worth a mention. Sorry it doesn't work as advertized in MSDN (not everything does).

Comment: Oh, no worries. Sorry if I came off as rude. I'm going to mess around with setting the IsOpen property in the Closed event and see if that gets me anywhere. I'll update this post if it comes through